# Where should I declare an instance in c++?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, instances, cfiledialog

Such a newbie question I know but I can't seem to find any answers online. Basically I am using the CFile Dialog and not sure if I should put it in the .cpp file or the header file. Thanks in advance.

```
CFileDialog( BOOL bOpenFileDialog, 
             LPCTSTR lpszDefExt = NULL, 
             LPCTSTR lpszFileName = NULL, 
             DWORD dwFlags = OFN_HIDEREADONLY | OFN_OVERWRITEPROMPT, 
             LPCTSTR lpszFilter = NULL, 
             CWnd* pParentWnd = NULL );
```

**edit by ChrisBD**

Okay, so I have added the includes to my FileDialogDlg.cpp and added the code:

```
CFileDialog fileDlg( TRUE, 
                     NULL, 
                     NULL, 
                     OFN_ALLOWMULTISELECT | OFN_HIDEREADONLY, 
                     "All Files (.)|*.*||", 
                     this); 

// Initializes m_ofn structure 
fileDlg.m_ofn.lpstrTitle = "My File Dialog"; 

// Call DoModal 
if ( fileDlg.DoModal() == IDOK) 
{ 
    CString szlstfile = fileDlg.GetPathName(); // This is your selected file 
                                               // name with path

    AfxMessageBox("Your file name is :" +szlstfile ); 
}
```

My compiler is still showing a load of errors

Comment: Can you post up the errors that you're getting and check that I've added your code correctly into your question please.

Comment: Ah I posted the errors once but they seemed to dissapear. error C2664: 'CFileDialog::CFileDialgo(BOOL,LPCTSTR,LPCTSTR,DWORD,LPCTSTR,CWnd*,DWORD)': cannot convert parameter 5 from 'const char [20]' to 'LPCTSTR'

the other is error C2440: '=': cannot convert from 'const char '[15]' to 'LPCWSTR'

Comment: You can't add a CString to a char array like that. You need to build your string for the AfxMessageBox. I'd suggest using ostringstream..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My bet regarding the "cannot convert parameter 5 from ..." error is that you compile your app as Unicode (which is a good thing). You must then use Unicode-aware string literals in your code for string parameters:

```
CFileDialog fileDlg( TRUE,  
                     NULL,  
                     NULL,  
                     OFN_ALLOWMULTISELECT | OFN_HIDEREADONLY,  
                     L"All Files (.)|*.*||", // <-- I Added the leading L  
                     this);
```

You could also decide to make it both ANSI/Unicode compatible using the `TEXT()` macro or its `_T()` shortcut.

```
CFileDialog fileDlg( TRUE,  
                     NULL,  
                     NULL,  
                     OFN_ALLOWMULTISELECT | OFN_HIDEREADONLY,  
                     _T("All Files (.)|*.*||"), // <-- _T("blah")
                     this);
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer is *neither* - the `CFileDialog` class is already declared for you in `afxdlgs.h` (according to the [`CFileDialog` documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dk77e5e7%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)), so just:

```
#include <afxdlgs.h>
```

Then you can use `CFileDialog` in your code.

Comment: Okay, so I have added the includes to my FileDialogDlg.cpp and added the code: 

CFileDialog fileDlg( TRUE, NULL, NULL, OFN_ALLOWMULTISELECT | OFN_HIDEREADONLY, "All Files (*.*)|*.*||", this);
// Initializes m_ofn structure
fileDlg.m_ofn.lpstrTitle = "My File Dialog";
// Call DoModal
if ( fileDlg.DoModal() == IDOK)
{

My compiler is still showing a load of errors. 
CString szlstfile = fileDlg.GetPathName(); // This is your selected file name with path
AfxMessageBox("Your file name is :" +szlstfile );
}

My compiler is still showing a load of errors.

Comment: We can't properly help you unless you show (a) your code, and (b) the errors from your compiler.

Comment: Okay I am getting three errors. error C2678: binary '+': no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'con char [20]' (or there is no acceptable conversion) 
error C2664: 'CFileDialog(Bool,LPCTSTR,LPCSTR,DWORD,LPCSTR,CWnd*,DWORD)':cannot convert parameter 5 from 'const char [22]' and error C2240 '=': cannot convert from 'const char [15] to 'LPCWSTR'. The only code I have enetered is the code in the above post.

Comment: It looks like you are compiling in Unicode mode. Use `_T("All Files...")` and use `TCHAR` wherever you have used `char`.

Comment: I have done as said and it is coming up with error C2440 still as well as C2143, C2065 and C2059.

Comment: Sorry, you're not being forthcoming with enough actual information. I'm afraid I can't help you without a lot more detail.

Comment: Basically all I want to do is just create a very basic open file dialog window. All I have done so far is openened Visual Studio 2005 and created an MFC dialog application. I have added a button to the dialog and created an event handler. Underneath the event handler I added the code above. I'm sure I am over complicating things, sorry about that. If there is any other information you need please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you create a new instance locally, set its properties and then open it modally. For example:

```
// Create an Open dialog; the default file name extension is ".txt".
   CFileDialog fileDlg (TRUE, "txt", "*.txt", OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST| OFN_HIDEREADONLY, szFilters, this);

   // Display the file dialog. When user clicks OK, fileDlg.DoModal() 
   // returns IDOK.
   if( fileDlg.DoModal ()==IDOK )
   {
      CString pathName = fileDlg.GetPathName();

      // Implement opening and reading file in here.
      ...
   }
```

Comment: Sorry to be a pain in the backside but what do you mean locally? Is this my normal .cpp or header file or my dialog .cpp or .h file. Thanks.

Comment: Variables and instances declared and created within a function or procedure, prior to use are said to be declared/created locally. They are only in scope whilst that function is being processed.